# XDocument automatically indents files on parse and does not remove indent on save

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, linq-to-xml, indentation

I am seeking a help regarding file saving of XML file using XDocument (NOT XMLDocument).

So I have a xml file that does not have indentation (in fact it is 1 line). When I read this to XDocument using XDocument.Parse (after reading and storing string using `StreamReader`), the resulting XDocument is indented.

Alright, I thought it will be fine as long as if I can save it back to the file without indentation. However, even though I have

```
XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
writerSettings.NewLineOnAttributes = false;
writerSettings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None;
writerSettings.Indent = false;
```

and pass that in when I create XmlWriter

```
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(u.ToFileSystemPath(), settings))
{
    xd.Save(writer);
}
```

The resulting XML file still has indentation. When I am debugging on Visual studio, I noticed that the `writer` is a class `XmlWellFormedWriter`. Does this have something to do with my result? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce this... it works fine for me when parsing using `XDocument.Parse(...)` and then saving with the code you've given. Could you produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: The code above saved you a XML file that does NOT have indentation?

Comment: Yes this code worked after removing all location that had LoadOption.PreserveWhiteSpace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SaveOptions are available on `Save()` as well as `ToString()`.

```
    string xmlstring = 
@"<Top>
    <First>1</First>
    <Second>Dude</Second>
    <Third>Now</Third>
</Top>";

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
    doc.Save(@"C:\temp\noIndet.xml", SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
        // string noIndent = doc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: My goal is to save file back to XML document. So just having string that is not indented does not really achieve my goal. I do have non indented string when I read from buffer. Thanks.

Comment: @publicst119 I updated the code to show you how to perform the Save as well.

Comment: hmmm... the moment debugger hit the save, because the indentation is there on Parse result (in XDocument), the saved file gets back the indentation. This is odd. I made sure there are no extension method or anything but still no result. Now the `string tepm = xd.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);` That you suggested earlier has indentation as well.

Comment: herm right after I used the .Parse, it that string is becoming unindented. However, when I use it at the end it does not. There must be code in between that is forcing it to save those indentation.

Comment: Sure enough... there was location where it had LoadOptions.PreserveWhiteSpace. Thanks for the hassle but after that it definitely works.